# React transition group with CDN

Tags: reactjs, transition, cdn

I'm using React on an existing app and I imported react with  in my html file.

My slideshow ( I'm coding a slideshow ) is working but I'd like to add some animations.

On a traditional npm project I would import CSSTransitionGroup,

but on my project I found this file : 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-transition-group/2.5.0/react-transition-group.js

I imported it but I have the message : 
CSSTransitionGroup is not defined,

would you have a solution to use react transition group in an existing project?